# Setting permission at item level in a List

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, permissions

I have noticed that it's possible to manage permissions at an item level in folder lists (open a folder list, click on an item, go to 'shared with', then click 'advanced', and here you are).

Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to be possible with folders inside a regular list. When I go into a regular list, click on an item, go to 'shared with', the 'advanced' button simply isn't there.

Is there something I have to do in order to make it available ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found "a" solution the my problem, though it only allows me to set permission: it doesn't solve the fact that there's no button to access the permission interface for some items.

Despite the fact that the interface might not be accessible through a link, one can still directly get it through an URL.

http://mysharepoint.com/_layouts/15/User.aspx?List=%7B#{list_guid}%7D&obj={#{list_guid}},#{item_id},LISTITEM

- Replace #{list_guid} by the list GUID.
- Replace #{item_id} by the ID of the item.

And you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

To enable unique permissions for list items you should follow

1. Using the ellipse menu - Select Manage Permissions
2. Then from ribbon click on - Break Inheritance
3. Now remove the existing permission & Grant new permission

Note - When you click on "Stop Inheriting Permission" following popup will appear.

[image]

If you read it, it says LIST ITEM.

Comment: But isn't that how to get global permission management for all the list ? I'm not trying to set permissions on all the items of a list, I'm trying to set unique permissions on a single item from a list.
I tried just breaking the inheritance on list level, but the 'advanced' button in the sharing settings for each individual item of the list still doesn't appear: the items themselves still inherits their permission from their list.

Comment: No, if you can do this for item level. See my updated screen shot.

Comment: Alright, thank you ! My guess is that the "Manage Permission" entry from the ellipse menu doesn't appear on my interface. I do have a "Shared with..." entry that shows a pop-up with the people having access to the item.
In the folder lists, that pop-up has an `advanced` button that leads to the permission interface (where the ribbon has the 'break inheritance' button). In my regular list, that pop-up has no `advanced` button.
I was fairly certain I was using Sharepoint 2013, but it might actually be Sharepoint 2010... I don't even know how to check that !